# Mikroorm check if entity is deleted

Tags: mikro-orm

em.nativeDelete returns how many entities are deleted so I can do:

```
const count = await this.em.nativeDelete(User, {id});

if(!count){
    throw new EntitiyNotFoundException(`User with id: ${id} is not found`);
}
```

Is there a way to do the same with remove(). It returns the EntityManager how can I check if the there is an entity deleted:

```
const user = this.em.getReference(User, id);
await this.em.remove(user);
```

Answer (score 2):

With `em.remove()` you would first need to load the entity to see if it exists, there is no way to access the deleted count from UoW as flushing is not bound to that particular query, it can consist of many queries for many different entities/tables and operations (CRUD).

You want to do that inside explicit transation, to ensure other requests won't delete the record you just retrieved from database.

```
await em.transactional(async em => {
  // this will throw if not found, you might want to use `em.findOne` and 
throw yourself
  const user = await em.findOneOrFail(User, id);
  em.remove(user); // flush will be called automatically when using explicit transactions
});
```

Comment: I was using this approach I just didn't want to hit the database twice? Is there a reason to wrap it in transactional if findOneOrFail will throw and not reach remove anyways or is it just to omit the flush?

Comment: if you dont do both queries in transaction you can face race conditions (two reqs try to do the same, both will pass the find check but only one will actually remove the entity). without that the select query will be executed outside of the transaction

Comment: I had the idea that transactions have nothing to do with concurrency. Because flush and commit will be called at the end of the transaction, anyways. Here in the docs there is optimistic-locking that uses locks for that kind of behaviour https://mikro-orm.io/docs/transactions/#optimistic-locking. Also isnt mikroOrm doing transactional by default explained on top of the same page?

Comment: it has everything to do with concurrency. flush will run things in transaction, but you want that select to be part of it too, and flush is only about writes (create/update/delete queries). optimistic locking works for updating, we are talking about deletes here.

Comment: Yes, but one transaction will only see the work of the another transaction only after flush so even if you wrap it in transactional they both can take the same entity and there will be a race condition. Because transactinal doesn't lock another transaction from taking the same entity and also in the same page there is: 'Pessimistic Write (LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE), locks the underlying database rows for concurrent Read and Write Operations.'

Comment: From the same page: 'If transactions are executed serially (one at a time), no transaction concurrency exists. However, if concurrent transactions with interleaving operations are allowed, you may easily run into one of those problems:
1.The lost update problem
2.The dirty read problem
3.The incorrect summary problem'